# Passing an argument to method within the function

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and been having some issues trying to understand why this code doesn't work. I am trying to pass a function argument to a method argument within the function. Here is my code:

```
import datetime
    
starter = datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 21, 16, 29)
    
def time_machine(integer, string):
    if string == 'years':
        string = 'days'
        integer *= 365
    return starter - datetime.timedelta(string=integer)
```

When I try this I simply get a TypeError.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete code (i.e. the call to `time_machine()`), expected output, and the full error message with traceback. You can [edit] to add it. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: What, **exactly**, is the error you are getting? Post the full error message including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is not a valid parameter for `datetime.timedelta`

Use instead `datetime.timedelta(days=integer)` or `datetime.timedelta(integer)`:

```
def time_machine(integer, string):
    if string == 'years':
        integer *= 365
    return starter - datetime.timedelta(days=integer)
```

example:

```
>>> time_machine(2, 'years')
datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 21, 16, 29)
```

or to pass a parameter name programmatically:

```
def time_machine(integer, string):
    if string == 'years':
        string = 'days'
        integer *= 365
    else:
        assert string in ('days', 'seconds', 'microseconds',
                          'milliseconds', 'minutes', 'hours', 'weeks'
                         ), 'invalid parameter'
    return starter - datetime.timedelta(**{string: integer})
```

example:

```
>>> time_machine(2, 'minutes')
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 21, 16, 27)
```

Comment: @ayhan I'll add this, but in any case this works only if the passed string is a valid parameter for `timedelta`